# Exclude final column in row selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, row

I have a script that if I click anywhere in the row it takes me to the link found in column 1.  It works great.  However I want to put a button in the final column, and if I click the button, it takes me to the link in the first column.  So I want my script to exclude the final column.  However, now when I click in a cell instead of taking me to the link in the first cell of the row, it takes me to the link in the first column, first row. Or a better solution would be to exclude only the button from the script, not the entire cell.  How would I exclude that from this script below?

```
<script>
    $('tbody tr td:not(:last-child)').click( function() {
    window.location = $('tbody tr td').find('a').attr('href');
    }).hover( function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('hover');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use another click function on your button with stopPropagation. For example:

```
$('tbody tr td').click(function(){
  //its ok, dont change this
});

$('.yourButton').click(function(e){
 e.stopPropagation();
 // do your stuff
})
```

Made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a2Sd6/

Next problem:
Workaround (without stopPropagation()): http://jsfiddle.net/a2Sd6/1/

Comment: This works great.  never seen stopPropagation before. However I am using twitter bootstrap and the Im using a drop button.  The stopPropagation prevents the button from working, since the button uses jquery in that class. any way to get that functioning?

Comment: This worked except using a drop down called a second event on an <A> tag which would apply the original event call. Changing the e.target to the following made it work:  if (e.target.nodeName =='BUTTON' || e.target.nodeName =='A'){